# regex gives to much digits

Tags: regex

I am searching for a `invoicenumber`, with the regex `'Invoicenumber: (//d+)'`.
But unfortunately the line contains also a employer name, and some of these names also contains digits, e.g. '`xs4all`', so the result is the `invoicenumber` + the digits '4' of the name. How can I prevent this from happening?

Example 1

```
xs4all                   Invoicenumber: 123456  gives 1234564 (wrong)
```

Example 2

```
anothername              Invoicenumber: 112233  gives 112233 (good)
```

Comment: Show your code and the exact example that is not working. It seems impossible to match the 4 (or any digit) out of `xs4all` with the given regex.

Comment: Can you post the entire line? Where does 123456 come from?

Comment: I don't understand how come the `4` in result if you have regex `Invoicenumber: (\d+)` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing correct character escape in your regex (unescaped forward slash) that you are posted.

This one should works

```
/Invoicenumber: (\d+)/g
```

[image]

Comment: The actual code I used is 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "Invoicenumber: (\\d+)" );

Your code gives an error
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \
 \ )

It it used with the pdfbox library.

Comment: Sorry, I ment inserting your code in my java program indicate an the given error.

Comment: Sorry but I don't work with Java, so I'm not sure how Regex works there.The Regexr display correct results.